# How can I remove the background of a video if the background is still?

Tags: premiere

In example,
I have this exported Image from a video001

[image]

then someone enter to the room without move anything from the image and then leave.

There is a way to use the image as a keymap to remove every match from the video001 with the image?

The result should be only the differences between the video001 and the image.

I use Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2018, but if there is other tools to obtain that result, tell me please.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sequence, place a still frame of the background with your footage place above.

> - V2: Footage
> - V1: Still frame of background

In the Effects panel, find Video Effects > Keying > Difference Mask. Drag this effect onto your footage (the top-most track).

[image]

In the Effects Control panel, set the 'Difference Layer' to match the track with the still frame.

[image]

Hide the still frame (bottom track) using the 'Toggle Track Output'. The background will now be transparent.

[image]

Inconsistencies of lighting, shadows and movement of the background will have a big effect on the quality of the outcome.

Avoid casting shadows on the background by keeping the scene well lit. Be aware of objects in the background moving.

If necessary, use a combination of color keying (a wall with a solid colour that contrasts with the subject) as well as masks to hide parts of the footage where no movement occurs.